# Huffman Decoding with recursion

Tags: python, recursion, huffman-code

I am creating a huffman class that can encode and decode text but I am having trouble with my decode method. My encoding method works fine and my decoding method works for smaller amounts of text. But when I try to decode large amounts of text I get a maximum recursion depth error and am not sure how to fix it. The class takes in a dictionary with characters and their frequencies and then turns them into nodes and builds the tree. After building the tree it puts the characters and their bitcode into another dictionary to be used for encoding and decoding.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value,data,left=None,right=None):
        #Holds frequency
        self.value = value
        #Holds character
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.code = ""
    
    def __lt__(self, other):    
        return self.value < other.value       
    
    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.value <= other.value
       
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.value > other.value
      
    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.value >= other.value

class MyHuffman():
 def __init__(self):
    self.chars = {}
    self.tree = None
    self.decodePosition = 0
    
 def build(self, weights):
        huffNodes = []
        heapq.heapify(huffNodes)
        for x, y in weights.items():
            heapq.heappush(huffNodes,Node(y,x))
        
        while len(huffNodes) > 1:
            left = heapq.heappop(huffNodes)
            right = heapq.heappop(huffNodes)
            left.code = 1
            right.code = 0
            heapq.heappush(huffNodes, Node(left.value+right.value, left.data + right.data, left, right))

        self.tree = huffNodes[0]
        self.makeLookupTable(self.tree)
        
    
 def makeLookupTable(self, node, bitCode=""):
      codes = bitCode + str(node.code)
      if node.left == None and node.right == None:
        self.chars[node.data] = codes
      else:
          self.makeLookupTable(node.left, codes)
          self.makeLookupTable(node.right, codes)
      return self.chars

    
 def encode(self, word):
     bitString = ""
     for x in range (0, len(word)):
         if word[x] in self.chars:
             for y, z in self.chars.items():
                 if word[x] == y:
                     bitString = bitString + z
     return bitString                

      
 def decode(self, bitstring):
     for x in bitstring:
         if x != "0" and x != "1":
             return None
     dec = self.recursiveTraverseTree(self.tree,bitstring)
     self.decodePosition=0
     return dec
 
    
 def recursiveTraverseTree(self, node, bitString, words=""):
     if node.left == None and node.right == None:
         words= words + str(node.data)
         node = self.tree
         
     if self.decodePosition < len(bitString):         
             if bitString[self.decodePosition] == "0":                
                    self.decodePosition+=1
                    return self.recursiveTraverseTree(node.right, bitString, words)
             elif bitString[self.decodePosition] == "1":
                    self.decodePosition+=1
                    return self.recursiveTraverseTree(node.left, bitString, words)
     
     return words
```

Some test runs below
The first test works fine but the second gives a maxRecursion depth error

```
huff = MyHuffman()
freqs = {'z': 50, 'j': 1, "'": 11, 'a': 42, 'd': 3, 'l': 1, 'f': 14, ' ': 31, 'i': 1, 'w': 8, 's': 41, 'r': 2, 'k': 49, 'b': 28, 'q': 28, 'p': 32, 'g': 33, 'v': 51, 'c': 6, 'h': 6, 'm': 5, 'y': 8, 'o': 36, 't': 28, 'u': 23, 'n': 15}
b = huff.build(freqs)
word = "damn son"
bitstring = huff.encode(word)
decrypted = huff.decode(bitstring)
print(f"[{word}] -> [{bitstring}] -> [{decrypted}]")
#Outputs[damn son] -> [1000011001110000101000110010100010110001] -> [damn son]
word1 ="bgzqbbvkqpaawaoasczz nfq szbumq'vzmbvbknsvvqouapcpbzkvbgtbsggcohto p tzhytz kkutanbv ubsbaogasznr tzz pzzsgqfqpsnfugsktpuzztq s vkfzavokoogmvzgpk tagkz zaoz'vaqpqkvbuvqtsbzgf zk kuzasovhauoqwtvvvovko  fvbwhzpvpkskouaupspstbvgsbszipqvvuvmuaspzna stvvk gu saaokggnmsvtspkvqvsahvozsawszfpws skgg bqkqu salg fovuknaknpupovafbovqssagpgbfkcuz gf ofgyrokasgc  guabqzbtkosqzbzvspzwgnsyfhvoz akgo'htsovzpakabayffpkpkvqrpzzqogsfvvatsvqbaapozavuyovzpbzsz ppuzrqbq'jaq zuqhhpptvkguktcbkazsszsgvocppzptzzhtzgt b mkznz qqk avkmztzsbzkgrovkqsssb pvtvssoutssazasunaavgybffppqgqagbsa gqscwpno'pb qsknzagtu pztqfbmbztmtuzktvza gaovapkvav govpv oazg'qgrpyszvqqzvgvztbavsy pswurtauztkztavv zcqvzs gbt zgzosfvtpk'gyggbokt ktgukzgskfzf ntavpq bzazvtphvcfba knp'zg'vsyqtvuopz tvzks fn'boaakyvskgvgqggqz tknqbbbvskavkgqpskkkvapca rvzpkksvw'p spvhbzfgggzz'fopfsngoujykutkapbvtqzkkaanpogpnozohvqgfwkdpkvgdpouku v zpkkonuzks oznspqz'aszvnt v ytkcptstkftcknfksbkqszqht z wmpafzwf vkofvadvaqagqzpnzavvuzqkau nqobvggzp qv gup fokkbsoaqkoz svu uvzqzzpyfwuq ozszkzspkavsvta tgovt zpyqvpkzpbnvbsakkgvaktkqwukozp zskzr a aobzopg qtmkakk g nz vgagaktwv tptw bfqmsogzhhkpzwaza tokcbta kzzutvzk zvkunqoowako zabvvkqu'zb kp  kvakvthgytvsvstpbvngvskgaqnfkokwozbztgszh'pgbopsgdnvzvozzgvsvgpvuzbuvkzat"
bitstring1 = huff.encode(word1)
decrypted1 = huff.decode(bitstring1)
print(f"[{word1}] -> [{bitstring1}] -> [{decrypted1}]")
#Gives maximum recursion depth error
```

Comment: You should step through the code in a debugger to see if it's in an infinite loop, and if so, why. You didn't mention that you'd done any actual debugging so that's why I assume you haven't done that. It's a really basic step though, it would really help if you did that first and then shared the results of your debugging here. I recommend the [Pycharm debugger](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html) for beginners.

Comment: rewrite `decode` in loops instead of recursion entirely or partially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sketch (untested), which rewrite `decode` in loop and keep tree search in recursion.

```
    def decode(self, bitstring):
        for x in bitstring:
            if x != "0" and x != "1":
                return None

        pos = 0
        size = len(bitstring)
        dec = ""

        while pos < size:
            pos, word = self.decode_one(self.tree, bitstring, pos)
            dec += word

        self.decodePosition = 0
        return dec

    def decode_one(self, node, bitstring, pos):
        """Return a tuple of the smallest unused position and the word"""
        if node.left == None and node.right == None:
            return pos, node.data
        elif bitstring[pos] == "0":
            return self.decode_one(node.right, bitstring, pos + 1)
        elif bitstring[pos] == "1":
            return self.decode_one(node.left, bitstring, pos + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`word1` has a length of 1260. Huffman code uses at least 1 bit per letter. As a result `bitstring1` is at least 1260 bits long. `decode` recurses once for every bit decoded, or at least 1260 times. That is more than Python's default limit of 1000, so you get the error.

Comment: I never knew that!   Further research would show that you can raise the limit with `sys.setrecursionlimit(x)` where x is your new limit.  Say, 2000?

Comment: @RufusVS. Raising the limit just means it takes a larger input to hit the new limit. Maybe that's good enough, but hitting the limit is often a sign that you should revise your algorithm.

Comment: Certainly a deep-stack recursion algorithm would merit an algorithm change to reduce or eliminate the depth of recursion, (e.g. sorting the shorter subset in a quicksort algorithm first).  I didn't look at the actual algorithm in the OP code.